# How to synthetize a 10 kHz signal from 1 Hz analogically

Tags: pll, synthesizer

I would like to synthesize a 1 Hz signal to a 10 kHz one without using MCU or related DPLLs.

Anyone has a schematic example? I found this reference schematic on Art of Electronics.

Would that suit (changing values for the pump) or maybe is there a better way to do it?

[image]

Comment: If you want to operate a phase detector at 1 Hz, you'll need a filter with a very long time constant at its output. Note that the 60 Hz design above is already using a time constant of over 3 seconds! How long are you willing to wait for the system to achieve phase lock?

Comment: any time is fine. It can be achieved also in several hours eventually as will be just for a proto-board and for discipline an OCXO eventually

Comment: 4046 running at 10kHz with a 10k divider would be the cannoical way to do it. With careful filter design, it could settle in 5 clock cycles, though longer would be easier.

Comment: A PLL is the way to do it.  This schematic you drew is a PLL.

Comment: Note that a clock divider that counts is actually a digital circuit, even if it's not part of an MCU. It fulfills both criteria for "digital" time-discrete events only, and only a finite amount of signal states. On top of that, a counter/divider is even a finite state machine. So, your title and your schematic contradict

Comment: But between the two of us (and the whole internet that could read this): you're trying to discipline an OCXO. You typically only need an OCXO if you need better frequency precision than 10 Parts per million (PPM) relative error. Now, you plan to add a somewhat superficially understood control loop to it, and says you don't care about convergence behavior. That won't work out, and also not in "a few hours", because in that time you'll already have to correct the drift off your oscillator. **Your circuit needs to be really well-designed, because its job is being something really good better**.

Comment: As you approach this currently, you expect that since arbitrary solution for another problem is a solution that fits yours, and that will make your ocxo actually have *more* jitter than it would have without your control loop starting to pull around on it. Devices that I've seen that do the job you want to do here, discipline a relatively high-quality 10 MHz oscillator from a GPS pulse per second, are very much analog control loops, but with digital logic defining loop properties based on computational models of the oscillator. That might be overkill here, but before you get concrete design

Comment: advice, you'll actually have to put information on your oscillator, its current frequency accuracy, the 1Hz source, and at least a sensible estimate on both things' jitter into numbers and add them to your question. Currently, you're not telling us how much you expect to need to discipline, and how well your 1 Hz is suited for that, and guessing will sadly not take us very far here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You totally got me :) . The source (1Hz) would  be indeed coming from the 1PPS. Actually I would like to explore the schematic of this Japanese guy http://www5a.biglobe.ne.jp/jh2clv/1hzphasedet.htm because I am curious on how he actually created a 50% duty cycle from the 1PPS of the GPS receiver using a 74HC04. Then the resulting would be to synth a 10lkHz and feed a 4046. On the other side, using decade dividers in parallel will divide the OCXO (  this Vectron https://www.ebay.com/itm/265999209547 )  to 10 kHz , reaching the 4046 comparator

Comment: and the ECV pin of the OCXO with the resulting .

Comment: The Japanese website actually he used the crazy idea to discipline it with 1Hz witch is too slow and I am afraid will not work out.

Comment: @Ken90 serious question, there's GPS modules with a GPS-disciplined 10 MHz out. Wouldn't that make your whole problem worlds easier?

Comment: Of course not, otherwise what is the meaning to build one?

Comment: I think will definitely will buy an AD9545  since there is a lot of code available for that DPLL evaluation board . But thanks the same. Indeed the most basic ones I saw online , from China they uses EPM3064A with a microcontroller, but was hit from the Japanese approach. BTW , since it is between me and you (and the public internet) there are some other circuit available online that reach the scope using GPS with already built in a 10 kHz exit ,like the Jupiter T https://www.sdradio.eu/g4jnt/gpsdo.html , so Your approach I think is correct but too holistic .

Comment: and they don't use digital logic or MCU to discipline the OXCO but simple PLLs logic...